# Google App Script: Execute a function of an addon thru a button (image)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'm wondering in which ways one can access the functions of an google sheets addon.

I'm currently working of a project which I had tried to give the feeling of an app to the best of my capabilities, such as:

[image]

However, in order to protect the code I'm planning to create an addon that contains most (if not all) of the functions.

Once the script it becomes an addon I'm planning to add a menu to access these functions.. losing some of the visuals that the user is so fond of.

I'm wondering if there is a way to access the scripts of an addon thru the buttons or a workaround. I've researched quite a few sites and tutorials but no luck yet.

Thought of maybe it was possible to add key shortcuts to the menu options but it seems is not possible either.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Sadly, this is not possible. Scripts bound to image buttons in a spreadsheet cannot call methods of an add-on. However, you can use HtmlService to create a sidebar or modal that can accept user input and invoke methods in your add-on. But you'll have to rethink how users interact with your app to effectively leverage that option since you'll have to move some interactivity away from the spreadsheet grid.

Comment: I'm sure a project like that would be much better suited to a web app rather than a sheet based app?

Comment: @JamesD Yea, however we decided to start the project on sheets for fast prototyping since the client didn't have a clear idea of what he needed and we went thru several iterations. Now that the prototype is in a more mature state, we will pass to the production on a web app, however I'd like to test the prototype on other companies in the sector and that's why this will evolve to an addon to protect the source code sacrificing some UX, sadly

Comment: @LuisAlbertoDelgadodelaFlo, were you able to solve "calling methods of add-on on image click "?

Comment: @Jayakrishnan noup:) I migrated to Google Appsheets